# npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am facing an issue that blows my mind and I really can't rid out of it.
When I try to install `cordova` in the following way:

> npm install -g cordova

Here is what I receive:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
```

I tried to re-install node, modified permissions, but it didn't work, I searched on how to solve it for more than 12hours. So far, I was not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

That is just a warning. More than likely, somewhere down the dependency chain of cordova, there is a dependency for a deprecated version of minimatch. You should still be able to use cordova even with this warning appearing.

Comment: That's causing me another issue by preventing ionic to detect `cordova`.. I guess that warning is the issue